# set command error in c shell script

Tags: shell, csh, tcsh

I am doing this on my script:

```
set Cnt1 =`echo $Cnt | awk '{print $1}'`
set Cnt2 =`echo $Cnt | awk '{print $2}'`
set Cnt3 =`echo $Cnt | awk '{print $3}'`
```

I am getting a error saying " set: Variable name must begin with a letter." Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong..
Cnt got value like this:

```
Cnt = 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must remove space between Cnt and =

```
set Cnt1=`echo $Cnt | awk '{print $1}'`
set Cnt2=`echo $Cnt | awk '{print $2}'`
set Cnt3=`echo $Cnt | awk '{print $3}'`
```

Please leave (t)csh, it's awful, and read [Top Ten Reasons not to use the C shell](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/CshTop10.txt)!

Comment: yes i am using tcsh script but now i am getting error of "Illegal variable name"

Comment: Note that the following are all legal: `set a=b`, `set a = b`, `set a= b`, but this is illegal: `set a =b`.

Comment: I truly hate csh